# laravel 7 + vue.js 3 + passport 401 Unauthorized

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-passport

Hello I amm trying to secure API with laravel passport, but always throws me 401 unauthorized.
where am i making a mistake? Any help? Thank you.

I added into User.php HasApiTokens,

and uncomment `'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy'` and added to boot Passport:routes() in AutServiceProvider.php,

in

```
auth.php 'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',]
```

**in RegisterController.php**

```
 protected function create(array $data)
    {

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
        $token = $user->createToken('API Token')->accessToken;
        return $user;
    }
```

**in bootstrap.js**

```
const token = '3acdc8cddb433947ea7cc51de909fdc50dcdf601ac521ac37ff1b3ee3a61e47e2111d297a07e147e'

window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
```

**in Posts.vue axios**

```
mounted() {
        axios.get('/public/api/posts').then(response=>{
            this.data =response.data
        })
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to provide oauth2 you might want to look at Laravel Sanctum which is more light-weight and easier to set-up (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#passport-or-sanctum).

But if you really need passport, first thing to check is if you followed every step in Passport's installation instructions (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#installation) such as `php artisan passport:install`

Comment: maybe i dont need provide oauth2 but i had same problem with sanctum, so i tried passport. and yes i do every step include passport:install

Answer (score 0):

I think you still need x-csrf-token in your headers.common

```
let csrf_token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (csrf_token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = csrf_token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

Comment: same problem...still 401 error, but .... in bootstrap.js is const token = ' '  i get api data , but if const token = ' here is token' i get 401 error, I think it's the other way around?

Comment: what is "token" referencing.  There is Auth Tokens and there are CSRF tokens.  do you have the csrf meta tag in your blade template head?

Comment: auth token.... and yes i have meta tag in my blade template

Comment: and you are using auth:api middleware on the /public/api/posts route?

Comment: and you have added the https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript  createfreshapitoken to your `app/Http/Kernel.php `

Comment: yes, but i have a little progress ... now i get error 500 "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'api_token' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `api_token` = 4cae65fb4850cd83f30b5ea5688f8e19c9b8bf6f99775a154d41ea033510e85a limit 1)" , if i create that in db and put token in , thats all works ... but i dont want api_token in users table

Answer (score 0):

May be this can be the late answer. but after clearing my caches the token now work like a charm.

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Helps me to fix my issues. Also you may give this a try

I had find out that after changing the `auth.php` file in the configuration to instruct `api` routes to use the right settings Laravel had already cached different values this become my tough when trying to clear those caches